# Multiple platform specific builds for single react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I want to develop a react js application that has specific platform code (Electron, Browser, Ionic).

First I made a library that wraps the platform-specific API in one interface like storage for example. I made a **StorageInterface** and a **Storage** class that implements the **StorageInterface** then I have **StorageElectron** class which inherits the **Storage** class same goes for **BrowserStorage** and **IonicStorage**. Now in my react app I just initiate the Service but I want to change it in build time.

Let's say I have this line of code `let storageService: StorageInterface = new Storage()`. When I enter `npm build electron` it builds with the **StorageElectron** class and when I enter `npm build web` it builds with the **StorageWeb** class instead of **StorageElectron**. The Storage class is just for the OOP norm it has only the headers of the methods but does not implement the functionalities.

I don't know if it's possible like this.

What I thought so far :

1- Create a Webpackloader or a precompiler that changes some lines of code in some files.

2- Create a precompiler using TypeScript decorators.

3- Create a simple script that changes the files that contain these calls before they react script.

I just want to know if there is a tool or a library able to do that.